# What MySQLi data type should be used for values from <option>

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to insert a value into a MySQLi row using a ***select*** box, as seen below.

```
<select name="post_game"><option value="minecraft">Minecraft</option></select>
```

**But I am faced with the error:**

```
Undefined index: post_game
```

Is this because I should be using a different data type as oppose to using Varchar? I am also inserting values into other MySQLi rows using < input > instead of < select >, and they seem to go through just fine, which is why I believe it may have to do with the data type, and not my code.

But here is my code anyway:

> ```
> <select name="post_game"><option value="minecraft">Minecraft</option></select>   
>
> $game=$_POST['post_game'];
> $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO servers (game) VALUES ('$game')");
> ```

Comment: Post your entire form code, or echo out $game to ensure it's getting the value when the form is posted.

Comment: How are you posting the data?

Comment: **DO NOT** ever put `$_POST` data directly in a query, it's extremely hazardous and creates a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should be using prepared statements and the [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method to add data to your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varchar will work just fine. If that is your entire code that you posted it won't work since there is not post request being made, in order to do that you need a form element

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="post_game">
        <option value="minecraft">Minecraft</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["post_game"]))
{
    $game = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["post_game"]);
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO servers (game) VALUES ('$game')");
}
?>
```

And also think about security as well. Bind your params, I'm on my phone so I wpnt get into that. This should be enough to get you going though

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write this answer, but the only answer I needed was whether not I should be using Varchar. I already have a connection to my database and the correct SQL code to access it, etc.

Comment: fair enough :p I didn't have powers to "comment" so I wanted to make it look like an answer